# Check if includeCss set

Tags: variable

I have created a field named inlineCss, which i'm using to set a pageCss variable. However, when no CSS is added to the entry, the `{% includeCss pageCss %}` is still adding a style tag in the head, albeit empty.

```
{% set pageCss %}
    {{ entry.inlineCss }}
{% endset %}

{% includeCss pageCss %}
```

Is there a way to only show the style tag if the pageCss variable is not empty?

I've tried checking for is defined and not null but it just keeps outputting the empty style tag.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you should be able to wrap it in an `if` statement like this...

```
{% set pageCss %}
    {{ entry.inlineCss }}
{% endset %}

{% if pageCss != ''  %}
    {% includeCss pageCss %}
{% endif %}
```